# check if a line exists in DB before displaying "add" button

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I've a table with contacts, a table with events, and a table that links contacts to those events.

So, in my view, I select an event and I can see a list of contacts that are allowed to be add to this event.

For the moment, it is possible to add a contact many times to an event.

I'd like to check if the contact is already add to the event before to display the button.

Here is my view :

```
 <td>
      @Code
      Dim flag1 As Integer = 0
      flag1 = (From a In Model.trans_Event
               Where a.FK_id_contact = item.idContact And a.FK_id_Event = idEvent
               Select a.idtrans).Count()
      End Code

      @If flag1 = 0 Then
      <input type="button" value="add" />
      Else
      <input type="button" value="delete" />
      End If
 </td>
```

This code like that doesn't work, and I don't really see how I can check whether the contact has already been add or not. Here is the error I get :

```
    Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: source
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at this code ( if you havent made a copy/paste mistake )

```
a.FK.id_Event = idEvent
```

you are trying to get a -> FK -> id_event and since there is no FK object in your model it breaks down to null exception.

looking at your code that should be "a.FK_id_Event"

```
flag1 = (From a In Model.trans_Event
               Where a.FK_id_contact = item.idContact And a.FK_id_Event = idEvent
               Select a.idtrans).Count()
      End Code
```

Edit:

when filtering the collections in the model i would prefer;

```
Model.trans_Event.Where(a => a.FK_id_contact == item.idContact && 
                             a.FK_id_Event == idEvent)
```

Comment: I made a copy/paste mistake (I speak french and I translate everything from french to english to have a code as understandable as possible).

Comment: your Model classes would be helpfull to the solution

Comment: your answer helped me to understand my fault. I was so sure that I did not use the "count" correctly that I haven't been further. In fact my problem was inside the controller that did not send the "trans_Event" table to the view.